# kafka compaction with compression process

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a Kafka topic with cleanup.policy=compact and a producer is producing data with compression type snappy with batch size and linger ms settings for higher throughput. From what I understand, the message batches are compressed on the producer side before sending to broker and the broker receives and stores the compressed messages. When a consumer reads the topic, the compressed batches are delivered to client and the decompression happens at client. There could be multiple producers to the same topic with different compression type as well.

When the compaction thread runs, for correct compaction, the messages would have to be decompressed on brokers, and after compaction the messages would have to be compressed again for efficient delivery to the client. But doing so might give a very uneven distribution of compressed batches depending on messages received, or what would be the compression type if different batches had different compression type. I could not find an explanation of how exactly compaction works with compression enabled on producer. Can someone help understand the process?

Thanks in advance.